# N channel depletion FET vs P channel enhancement Operation

Tags: mosfet

As the title implies I am confused about the electrical characteristics of N channel depletion FETs vs P channel enhancement mode fets. Won't both of these devices act similarly as they both have negative threshold voltages? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although both have negative threshold, the operation is still opposite. For N-channel, the gate voltage must be above the threshold voltage to allow conduction through the channel. For P-channel, the gate voltage must be below the threshold voltage to allow conduction.

Answer (score 0):

In an enhancement mode FET (whether P or N channel), the VGS(voltage) turns on current flow. If VGS = 0 V then no current flows from drain to source.
You will sometimes see this described as 'Normally Off'

In a depletion mode FET (whether P or  N channel), the VGS(voltage) turns off current flow. If VGS = 0 then maximum current flows from Drain to Source.
You will sometimes see this described as 'Normally On'

[This](http://www.dauniv.ac.in/downloads/Electronic%20Devices/12EDCMOSFETLesson12.pdf) might help.

Answer (score 0):

In N-channel FETs, the source is at a lower voltage than the drain, and more positive gate voltage results in more current flow.  In P-channel, the source is at the higher voltage, and more negative gate voltage results in more current flow.  This is true for both enhancement and depletion devices.

The difference between enhancement and depletion mode is whether the device is "OFF" or "ON" at Vgs = 0 (gate to source voltage).  Enhancement mode devices are "off" and require more positive (for N-channel) or more negative (for P-channel) voltages to turn them on.  Depletion devices are on with Vgs = 0, and need more negative (for N channel) or more positive (for P channel) to turn them off.

Enhancement FETs are easier to use since the supply voltage used for the drain can also be used for the gate.  Depletion mode FETs may need an extra supply voltage.  Most MOSFETs are enhancement mode.  All JFETs are depletion mode because of the need to maintain reverse bias on the PN junction used as the gate.